# How can I make my React application resize and zoom according to the browser window size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, frontend

I am doing one of my semester project in react and wanted your help.
I am redesigning one project https://en-roads.climateinteractive.org/scenario.html.
In this when we resize the browser the whole application shrinks and zooms according to the size of the browser window.
I tried using media queries but not able to achieve the same behaviour with that.
How can this be achieved ?

I tried using media queries but the output is not smooth and I saw my code is getting too complicated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are trying to achieve sounds like responsive design with fluid scaling, rather than the discrete breakpoints often used with CSS media queries.

To make your React application dynamically resize and zoom according to the browser window size, you can consider using CSS viewport units (vw, vh, vmin, vmax) and percentages (%). These units are relative to the viewport (the browser window size), so elements will automatically adjust their size when the window is resized.

For instance:

```
.myComponent {
    width: 80vw;  /* 80% of the viewport width */
    height: 50vh; /* 50% of the viewport height */
}
```

This will make .myComponent always take up 80% of the width and 50% of the height of the viewport, regardless of the window size.

Keep in mind that using viewport units alone may lead to issues with extremely small or large window sizes, as well as with accessibility (such as users with large default font sizes). You should also use minimum and maximum sizes (min-width, max-width, min-height, max-height) to prevent elements from becoming too small or too large.

As an advanced solution, you might also consider using a JavaScript library designed to help with scaling and responsiveness. One example is react-sizeme, which provides a higher-order component that can automatically update your components with the current window size.

Remember, designing for different viewport sizes can be complex, so it's best to test your application on a variety of screen sizes and devices to ensure it looks and works as expected.